# How to measure code execution time in VBScript or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

What is a good way to measure code execution time in [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript)?

Or failing that how to do it in [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For VBScript you can use Timer:

```
StartTime = Timer()
EndTime = Timer()
Response.Write("Seconds to 2 decimal places: " & FormatNumber(EndTime - StartTime, 2))
```

Or [ASP Profiler](http://aspprofiler.sourceforge.net/) (that is for an ASP environment.)

For JavaScript you can use Date:

```
var start = new Date().getTime()
alert("Milliseconds: " + (new Date().getTime() - start))
```

[Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28Firefox_extension%29) also has a profiler for JavaScript.

Comment: Wow there has been a great batch of replies here.  I think the "StartTime = Timer() EndTime = Timer()" method will work the best for me.  I don't need anything overly complicated or fine detailed and this works for my purposes.  Thanks.

Comment: The VBScript script behaves "strange" if midnight passes between the two Timer calls. Just saying

Answer (score 4):

For JavaScript, I would recommend you to use a profiler, like the one built-in in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/js.html):

[image]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](http://getfirebug.com/screenScript-profile.gif))</sub>

Other alternatives can be the one included with Google [Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/06/developer-tools-for-google-chrome.html), or [IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(VS.85).aspx)

If you want to do it programmatically, you could use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date) objects to get a time difference:

```
var startTime = new Date();
// ...
// ...
var endTime = new Date();
var delta = endTime - startTime; // difference in milliseconds
```

Comment: Note: using the Date approach, expect the accuracy of the times to be within 15ms at best (on Windows, at least): http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

Comment: You can expect the same accuracy issues in a firebug as you do in normal JavaScript execution. It also has the problem of an observer effect, slowing down your JavaScript because it runs in the same UI thread of the browser that the javascript does.

Comment: Firebug looks really cool.  It's more than I need for now but I likely have use for it down the road.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Found the perfect function with proper Hours/Mins/Secs formatting here: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/633.vbscript-determine-script-execution-time.aspx

**Usage:**

```
dtmStartTime = Timer
Wscript.Echo "Hello, World!"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
Wscript.Echo "Script completed in " & GetElapsedTime
```

**Function:**

```
Function GetElapsedTime
    Const SECONDS_IN_DAY    = 86400
    Const SECONDS_IN_HOUR   = 3600
    Const SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60
    Const SECONDS_IN_WEEK   = 604800

    dtmEndTime = Timer

    seconds = Round(dtmEndTime - dtmStartTime, 2)
    If seconds < SECONDS_IN_MINUTE Then
        GetElapsedTime = seconds & " seconds "
        Exit Function
    End If
    If seconds < SECONDS_IN_HOUR Then 
        minutes = seconds / SECONDS_IN_MINUTE
        seconds = seconds MOD SECONDS_IN_MINUTE
        GetElapsedTime = Int(minutes) & " minutes " & seconds & " seconds "
        Exit Function
    End If
    If seconds < SECONDS_IN_DAY Then
        hours   = seconds / SECONDS_IN_HOUR
        minutes = (seconds MOD SECONDS_IN_HOUR) / SECONDS_IN_MINUTE
        seconds = (seconds MOD SECONDS_IN_HOUR) MOD SECONDS_IN_MINUTE
        GetElapsedTime = Int(hours) & " hours " & Int(minutes) & " minutes " & seconds & " seconds "
        Exit Function
    End If
    If seconds < SECONDS_IN_WEEK Then
        days    = seconds / SECONDS_IN_DAY
        hours   = (seconds MOD SECONDS_IN_DAY) / SECONDS_IN_HOUR
        minutes = ((seconds MOD SECONDS_IN_DAY) MOD SECONDS_IN_HOUR) / SECONDS_IN_MINUTE
        seconds = ((seconds MOD SECONDS_IN_DAY) MOD SECONDS_IN_HOUR) MOD SECONDS_IN_MINUTE
        GetElapsedTime = Int(days) & " days " & Int(hours) & " hours " & Int(minutes) & " minutes " & seconds & " seconds "
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript, use the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/js.html) or [IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/09/11/introducing-the-ie8-developer-tools-jscript-profiler.aspx) profilers, or free [DynaTrace AJAX edition profiler](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/learn/testimonials.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you are trying to measure?

If are testing something and want to know how long certain pieces go, you could just declare a start and stop time variable, then do a difference between them....

Answer (score 0):

```
d = new Date();
x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 1e7; ++i) { x += i; }
d2 = new Date();
d2 - d

12296
```

Use the `Date` object, which returns a `valueOf()` in milliseconds since Jan 1 1970. You can then subtract times to get elapsed time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/643-how-to-measure-the-speed-of-javascript-execution/) is a great article on JavaScript timing, from the book "Even Faster Websites". Two things to keep in mind are that JavaScript Date objects often have a resolution as big as 15ms (this varies by browser and operating system), and most profilers have an [observer effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(information_technology)). Note that [Google Speed Tracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/) (new since the article was published) runs out of process and collects data asynchronously to minimize the observer effect.