# How to convert timer() value to minutes and seconds

Tags: vbscript

I am not good at math in VBScript.

I am struggling with this.

I want to count time in minute and seconds during my script execution.

```
stmr = Timer()
Wscript.Sleep 40000
m =FormatNumber(Timer() - stmr)/60, 0)
s = FormatNumber((Timer() - stmr), 0) - m*60
Wscript.Echo m & ":" &s
'=> 1m:-20s (wrong)

Wscript.Sleep 40000
m =(Timer() - stmr)/60
s = FormatNumber((Timer() - stmr), 0) - m*60
Wscript.Echo m & ":" &s
'=> 1m:20s (right)
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Get smoother code or is there some kind of error?

Comment: the format number is not right way to work with time. Please see my answer. Please give any suggestions to that method.

Comment: @Tom: First Wscript.Echo should give 0s : 40m instead of 1m: -20s.

Comment: But still... if your second solution works, whats the problem? O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to do using a `Timer()` as described in the documentation it;

> Returns the number of seconds that have elapsed since 12:00 AM (midnight).

In it's simplest form checking the elapsed time of your script requires you to take a start and end reading of `Timer()` and workout the difference.

```vb
Dim st, et

'Start Time
st = Timer()
'Long running task
WScript.Sleep 10000
'End Time
et = Timer()
'Display the difference
WScript.Echo "Time Elapsed (sec) :" & et - st
```

Output:

```
Time Elapsed (sec) :10.00391
```

Once you have the raw result in seconds you can do whatever you like to it, convert it to minutes and seconds, format it as a string do whatever you want. Just remember that functions like `FormatNumber()`, `FormatDateTime()` etc are designed to be used to show output and should never be used while performing calculations.

#### Update

Following on [from the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139824/how-to-convert-timer-value-to-minutes-and-seconds#comment63720877_38145327) an approach like [@Hackoo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080770/hackoo) [is acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38141883/692942) but can also be done without the need of `FormatNumber()`.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim st, i

st = Timer()
For i = 1 to 10
  WScript.Sleep 1000
  WScript.Echo FormatTime(Timer() - st)
Next

Function FormatTime(secs)
  Dim t, a
  secs = Int(secs)
  a = Array(CStr(Right("00" & Int(secs / 3600) Mod 24, 2)), CStr(Right("00" & Int(secs / 60) Mod 60, 2)), CStr(Right("00" & secs Mod 60, 2)))
  FormatTime = Join(a, ":")
End Function
```

*<sup>Becareful when using `Mod()` that any values you pass are whole numbers or you will get strange results (hence you use of `Int()` in the example)</sup>*

Output:

```
00:00:01
00:00:02
00:00:03
00:00:04
00:00:05
00:00:06
00:00:07
00:00:08
00:00:09
00:00:10
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [How to measure code execution time in VBScript or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1985822/692942)

Comment: What if I want to convert that timer value to hh:mm:ss value? That is not pretty straight forward. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is shorter. Is there any problem with my answer using  Now() method instead of timer()?

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject it comes down to how accurate you want the result to be, `Timer()` is designed for this purpose where as `Now()` isn't. Usually DateTime resolution accuracy can be as much as 15 milliseconds out.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try for this vbscript :

```
StartTime = Timer 'Start the Timer
Pause 80 ' pause in seconds
MyTime = FormatNumber(Timer - StartTime, 0) ' in seconds
DurationTime = TimeSpan(MyTime)
wscript.echo DurationTime

'*******************************
Function TimeSpan(MyTime)
seconds = FormatNumber(MyTime, 0)
minutes = seconds \ 60 
hours = minutes \ 60 
minutes = minutes mod 60 
seconds = seconds mod 60 
hours   = hours   mod 24 
if len(hours) = 1 then hours = "0" & hours
TimeSpan =  RIGHT("00" & hours , 2) & ":" & _ 
            RIGHT("00" & minutes, 2) & ":" & _
            RIGHT("00" & seconds, 2)
 End Function 
'*******************************
Sub Pause(NSeconds)
    Wscript.Sleep(NSeconds*1000)
End Sub  
'*******************************
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I got better way.

```
stmr = Now()
for i = 0 to 100
    Wscript.Echo (split(FormatDateTime((Now() - stmr), 3), ":")(0))-12 & "h : " _
    & split(FormatDateTime((Now() - stmr), 3), ":")(1) & "m : " _
    & split(split(FormatDateTime((Now() - stmr), 3), ":")(2))(0) & "s"
    Wscript.Sleep 1000
    i = i + 1
next
```